# How to authenticate to google-cloud-sdk using user account in non-interactive mode

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

When I am authenticating using service-account.json I am not able to access any projects, i.e. the command 'gcloud projects list' results in

> Listed 0 items.

Setting gcloud project using the command 'gcloud config set project my-project' results in:

> WARNING: You do not appear to have access to project [my-project] or it does not exist.

But this project is present in my service-account.json
I am trying to get my GKE cluster credentials to create a kubeconfig entry.
'gcloud container clusters get-credentials  my-cluster --zone=us-central1-a'

> ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=403, message=Required "container.clusters.get" permission(s) for "projects/my-project/zones/us-central1-a/clusters/my -cluster".

When I log in to GCP using gcloud init and logging in with user account all these steps are giving successful results. But how should I authorise user account without opening browser. I cannot use '--console-only' flag as it still requires to copy-paste url and opening browser. I want to automate the full process of authenticating to user account by only using scripts

NOTE: The my-cluster GKE cluster was created under my-project and was created by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect (!?) your service account has insufficient permissions (granted through roles).

To list projects (`gcloud projects list`), the service account must have (at least) `resourcemanager.projects.get` on (each of the projects) in the list. See:

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-proj#permissions_and_roles

To retrieve cluster permissions, it must have `container.clusters.get` (see [full list](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference)).

A good role that includes both is `roles/container.clusterAdmin`)

Service Accounts are challenging. They are both resources (particles) and identities (waves) and behave differently depending on context.

As resources, Service Accounts are created in (and owned) by a Project and may be granted permissions in **any** project (not just the owner).

As identities, Service Accounts may be granted roles that aggregate permissions to one of more methods. It is this step that I think you may be missing.

Google's [IAM documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview) is decent.